# How to merge top with bottom of a real 3d object with different lighting conditions?

Tags: texturing

I made two 3d models of a pot. One of the top part, one of a bottom part. I have simplified the mesh of both and baked the textures from high-poly. Now I want to merge them to be one uniform object.

The problem is, that both models were made with different lighting conditions. When I merge top with a bottom I get something like the attached picture. How can I make the texture look uniform? Will appreciate Your help, thanks.

[image: My object so far]

Comment: I believe that once the meshes have been merged, the texture must be recalibrated, since there were two previously, by merging the meshes the texture has merged as well. If I can give you some advice, you should always define and finish your object before applying the texture. Check what happened in the image editor. Alternatively you can upload the file from here:  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: To add:  if you plan to make a bunch of stuff to export and use somewhere you should define a standard uniform lighting situation so that your output is consistent.